# Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app

Tags: reactjs

Полная ошибка

> Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json »
> eslint-config-react-app »
> D:...\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig »
> D:...\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

Уже делал

```
npm uninstall  eslint-config-react-app

npm install  eslint-config-react-app
```

Снова появилась ошибка. Как ее исправить ? Из-за чего она возникает ?

Answer (score 0):

npm audit
npm audit fix --force

Куча предупреждений, но работает.

Comment: такая же проблема как у автора вопроса - Ваш вариант не сработал

Comment: попробуйте package.json и package-lock.json скопировать с другого, рабочего приложения React. Если в сборке ничего не меняли. Мне помогло также

Comment: Я создавал новый реакт проект, и была та же самая ошибка.Получилось решить путем создания абсолютно новой директории и переноса проекта туда с новым ```npx create-react-app```